# Space Tabulation before an paragraph

Tags: indentation

I want to add a tab before any paragraph 
my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm,
bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm,headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
citecolor=black,%
filecolor=black,%
linkcolor=black,%
urlcolor=black,%
pdftex}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{layout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\usepackage{float}
\lhead{\textit{\nouppercase\leftmark }}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titletoc}

% Ajustement de l'espace dans la table des matières
\newlength{\ecartnumero}
\setlength{\ecartnumero}{4mm}

%\dottedcontents{figure}%
%  [\dimexpr 7mm+\ecartnumero]{}
%  {\dimexpr 7mm+\ecartnumero}{1.2mm}


\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\begin{document}
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx . 
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

he print :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx . 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to add tabulation before  a paragraph  for example :

```
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx . 
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. To denote a paragraph, add an empty line in your code.

Comment: The same problem remains @TorbjørnT.

Comment: And the frist ligne of frist paragraphe ?

Comment: Try typing some actual text instead of long lines of x-es, as you can see, LaTeX doesn't hyphenate those, so you just get two very long lines.

Comment: For example, add `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ` twice, with an empty line between them.

Comment: Are you by any chance referring to the first line of the first paragraph after a section (or subsection, …) heading?  If so, just include `\usepackage{indentfirst}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

To create a paragraph break, leave one or more blank lines between lines of text

I've eliminated all code from the preamble that's not relevant to creating paragraph breaks.

[image]

As you can tell from the screenshot, the first lines of ordinary paragraphs are automatically indented (by the amount of `\parindent`, a length variable). If you also want the first lines of paragraphs immediately following `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. to be indented, load the package `indentfirst`, as @GustavoMezzetti has already noted in a commment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[inner=2cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm,
        bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm,
        headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\textit{\nouppercase\leftmark }}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx. 

xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you mention the `indentfirst` package too (see [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369481/space-tabulation-before-an-paragraph#comment912198_369481) above)?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Good idea. I've added a paragraph.